# Uwp: Xaml Parse Error with Target Device Family Desktop and Custom Styles

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

:)

I encountered a very weird error. I just completed work on my new UWP app. In my app I use custom styles for textBoxes and buttons (I created them by editing a template copy in Blend).

The app is for desktop use only, and I remembered that I have to declare that in my manifest. So I changed the Target Device Family to

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0"/>  
  </Dependencies>
```

But then I get a Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException on the custom style parts in my app. The app works perfectly fine when I delete these custom styles. And when I leave the target device family as it was before, Windows.Universal, everything also works fine with all the custom styles.

Do I miss something or is this just a bug?

Best wishes! :)

Comment: Could you please share your xaml code and your custom style, or maybe an issue-reproducable sample?