# UWP: Using Windows.Desktop target device family triggers XamlParseException - brush not found

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, enterprise, windows-community-toolkit

In the `Package.appxmanifest` file the following changes were made:

Before:

```
...
<Dependencies>
  <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
</Dependencies>
...
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
</Capabilities>
```

After:

```
...
<Dependencies>
  <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
</Dependencies>
...
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime" />
  <rescap:Capability Name="extendedExecutionUnconstrained" />
</Capabilities>
```

In addition some `App.xaml.cs` logic was introduced to deal with extended execution, as prescribed by this article (which has no impact on the issue as removing it does not change the outcome):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2018/01/30/non-suspending-uwp-desktop-apps/

Before running the application did not produce an error but after making the above changes it suddenly crashes when opening a page:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x802B000A
  Message=The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key SystemControlBackgroundChromeBlackLowBrush [Line: 193 Position: 121]
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
   at ...EventsView.InitializeComponent() in ..Client\Application.UWP\obj\x86\Debug\Views\EventsView.g.i.cs:line 43
   at ..EventsView..ctor() in Client\Application.UWP\Views\EventsView.xaml.cs:line 25
```

EventsView.xaml.g.i.cs at line 43:

```
global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocator, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ComponentResourceLocation.Application);
```

EventsView.cs at line 25:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FooViewModelDetailsDataTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodels:FooViewModel">
```

I'm not sure how changing the application target device family to `Windows.Desktop` would suddenly cause the application to be unable to find a certain brush.

I have removed all explicit brush assignments (of any brush) both in the XAML and in the view model but the error persists.

Also there isn't (nor was there) any line of code using the name `SystemControlBackgroundChromeBlackLowBrush` anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem and it seems I do not have the same XAML like you. So can you provide your target SDK version, OS version and then provide us the project which can reproduce your issue. If I simply use the demo from the blog nothing happens from my side.

Comment: I have just added the code and markup from the blog post to my project which itself contains much more XAML. I was looking for clues as to what I could be doing "wrong". But I'll to try make a minimal reproduction of the issue so the complete source is availble for inspection. Doing minimal repros seems to be the theme of this month. :-)

Comment: Just FYI: another similar case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714668/uwp-xaml-parse-error-with-target-device-family-desktop-and-custom-styles

Comment: The culprit appears to be the BladeView control from the Windows Community Toolkit. Will file a bug.

Comment: OK. Don't forget to add the git issue uri to here. Or we have no idea what happened for this specific question.

Comment: Github issue in WindowsCommunityToolkit repository: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2948

Comment: Thanks for the link. Others who meet the same issue can also track from it.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a bit late, but for anyone facing similar issues:
When I changed the TargetDeviceFamily Name from Windows.Universal to Windows.Desktop my application always crashed on launch.
To make it work I had to properly specify MinVersion and MaxVersionTested as it mentioned in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-targetdevicefamily).